# Moving files to different directories by file type in a batch file(Win)

Tags: sorting, batch-file, cmd, move, xcopy

Basically what I am trying to do is sort my downloads folder with a batch file. I need to know how to either make the batch file overwrite duplicate files or create a "(1)" at the end of the file name.
I am moving any file with .jpeg, jpg, etc... to my pictures folder and the like.
I currently have this,

```
@ECHO OFF
mkdir %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\EXEs
mkdir %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\Jars
mkdir %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\zips
mkdir %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\Crafts
mkdir %USERPROFILE%\Documents
mkdir %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\ISO's
mkdir %USERPROFILE%\Pictures
mkdir %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\Torrent
mkdir %USERPROFILE%\Music
mkdir %USERPROFILE%\Videos
mkdir %USERPROFILE%\Contacts


move %CD%\*.exe %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\EXEs 
move %CD%\*.jar %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\Jars
move %CD%\*.zip %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\zips
move %CD%\*.rar %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\zips
move %CD%\*.gz %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\zips
move %CD%\*.7z %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\zips
move %CD%\*.tar.gz %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\zips
move %CD%\*.craft %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\Crafts
move %CD%\*.pdf %USERPROFILE%\Documents
move %CD%\*.doc %USERPROFILE%\Documents
move %CD%\*.docx %USERPROFILE%\Documents
move %CD%\*.csv %USERPROFILE%\Documents
move %CD%\*.txt %USERPROFILE%\Documents
move %CD%\*.iso %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\ISO's
move %CD%\*.img %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\ISO's
move %CD%\*.jpg %USERPROFILE%\Pictures
move %CD%\*.jpeg %USERPROFILE%\Pictures
move %CD%\*.png %USERPROFILE%\Pictures
move %CD%\*.bmp %USERPROFILE%\Pictures
move %CD%\*.Torrent %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\Torrent
move %CD%\*.m3u %USERPROFILE%\Music
move %CD%\*.mp4 %USERPROFILE%\Videos
move %CD%\*.vcf %USERPROFILE%\Contacts
echo Sort Completed.
pause
```

And while this, for the most part, does the job. I still have a few files left behind and about 12 error messages,

> A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found.
>
> A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found.
>
> A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found.

I am fairly certain most of these messages are the program not finding "*.exe" and the like. Some, however are from some files left over that should be moved.
I have tried a lot of googling and came upon things more complex than I need.
Sorry if there is another post like this, I couldn't find it.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: You might try using `forfiles` (read `forfiles /?` for more info).  for example, `forfiles /m *.pdf /c "cmd /c move @file %userprofile%\documents`

Answer (score 2):

the error (probably) occures, if `move *.ext ...` can not find a file with the extension `.ext`. You could either

```
if exist *.ext move *.ext ...
```

or just redirect the errormessage to nirvana:

```
2>nul move *.ext ...
```

If you really want to overwrite any existing files in the destination: `move` has a `/y` parameter, that does exactly that. (Although `move /?` suggests, `move` does that per default when running from a batchfile)

For the remaining files I suggest another line at the end of your batchfile (when all other files have been moved):

```
2>nul move *.* %USERPROFILE%\Other
```

Answer (score 1):

1. To overwrite duplicate files add `/y` option to `move` command:

   move /y %CD%*.csv %USERPROFILE%\Documents
2. To append (1) to the end of file name you may check an existance first, eg in `forfiles` loop:

   forfiles /p %CD% /m *.csv /c "cmd /c if exist %USERPROFILE%\Documents\@file (move @path %USERPROFILE%\Documents\@fname^(1^).@ext) else (move @path %USERPROFILE%\Documents)"

This will rename file.ext to file(1).ext. But if there already will be file(1).ext, you will get the same issue. So it needs to be further improved, maybe some additional loop that will try (1), (2), (3)...

Comment: Appending something to file names may be tricky with `forfiles` as it returns the `@file` with surrounding double-quotes included...

Comment: @aschipfl you're right, as well as I didn't append to '@file'. But could '@fname' contain quotes? It needs to be checked

Comment: All file/dir.-path- and -name-related variables `@path`, `@relpath`, `@file`, `@fname` and `@ext` contain the surrounding `""` (unfortunately); all the others (type-, size- and date/time-related ones, `@isdir`, `@fsize`, `@fdate` and `@ftime`) do not return them...